# Apache server to run CGI scripts

Tags: python-2.7

i am trying to run some CGI scripts in python. For this i need apache server so, I installed XAMPP. Now my apache server is running.

I want to know what changes i need to make and in which file to link python with Apache server and to run my CGI scripts.

I am novice to python and that's why I have little knowledge about this.

I followed this link "http://jerryoem.wordpress.com/2008/03/31/how-to-run-python-cgi-script-under-windows-apache-server/"  and made changes to xampplite/htdocs. Earlier my Xampp was running apache server but after the changes it is showing error as:

```
Error: Apache service not started [-1]
```

Please suggest me the steps to work on it.